# VS2005, VSS - Check-in + Deploy automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I'm stuck working with VS2005 and VSS for some of the code that I'm working on. Are there any scripts that let me commit all modified source files to VSS and make VSS push out a patch to our QA servers?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [CruiseControl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/) to manage your build and drop?

It sounds like you wanted a bit extra ("scripts...commit all modified source files"), but CC.NET will take care of building/reporting/deploying. It's not clear from your question where the commits will be coming from (a developer machine, somewhere else), or why automated check-ins are useful. In other words, shouldn't developers be purposefully committing code changes?

[How to Setup CruiseControl.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ccnetprimer.aspx).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with CruiseControl, right now my VS install doesn't have any integration with VSS. I'm having to open a VSS Client (source offsite) and manually add check-in all the files that have been modified and add any files that have beem committed. Will take a look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server, which allows you to run build scripts after detecting changes in source control. Try [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [CruiseControl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/).

Here's a [walk through](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/01/27/source-control-and-continuous-integration-on-the-cheap) that details the setup process for CI with TeamCity and Subversion. You can add additional scripts for deployment via MSBuild or any command line tool.